# Passing multiple parameters with apply in Pandas

Tags: pandas

How do I pass multiple parameters with apply in Pandas?

`do_something` is a function:

```
def do_something(x,test="testFoo")
```

This can be used with `dataframe.apply`

```
df2.apply(do_something, test="testBar",axis=1)
```

I want to pass another parameter (df) like this:

```
def do_something(x,test="testFoo",df)
```

How do I now call apply with this `df` parameter similar to this:

```
df2.apply(do_something, test="testBar",df=df,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working small change `df=df` in `def`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'g':[50,40]})

def do_something(x,test="testFoo",df=df):
    print (df)
       a
    0  1
    1  2
       a
    0  1
    1  2

df2.apply(do_something, test="testBar",df=df,axis=1)
```

EDIT:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'g':[50,40]})

def get_df():
    return pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]})

def do_something(x,df,test="testFoo"):
    print (df)

df2.apply(do_something, test="testBar",df=get_df(),axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried this and get `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`.  I'm importing the function from another module.

Comment: @ade1e - I try edit question, important is order `do_something(x,df,test="testFoo")`